# I have substantially edited, expanded and improved my deleted answer. Kindly undelete or explain how to further improve my answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Request completed: soon after I posted the expanded and improved answer, members were kind enough to undelete. Your guidance and prompt response is much appreciated.

---

Edited: I have substantially edited, expanded and improved my recently deleted old answer to conform to current site expectations of quality. Kindly vote to undelete or explain how to further improve my answer to get it undeleted.

[How should I approach a situation in which I made a female roommate uncomfortable?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/how-should-i-approach-a-situation-in-which-i-made-a-female-roommate-uncomfortabl/1814#1814)

---

Original question:

As expected, my recently-accepted-and-highly-downvoted 4-month-old answer  got deleted. ***Now*** the delete-voters can help me by explaining the reasons for deleting this answer *after* it was accepted by OP. Meta.SE says that [poor answers need only be downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/362639), and only very low quality posts need to be deleted, but I am not especially proud of the original short answer and I am willing to improve the answer towards getting it undeleted: however, you got to tell me what's wrong with it!

Answers are especially welcome from the 3 delete-voters here because you can vote to delete again if somebody else votes to undelete. So you are the ones who must really be satisfied that my revised and expanded answer can be undeleted.

---

Many thanks to @Tinkeringbell and @Catija for providing useful [feedback](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/i-have-substantially-edited-expanded-and-improved-my-deleted-answer-kindly-und#comment5412_2310) that helped me understand how this answer needs to be improved to satisfy current site expectations of quality, towards undeletion.

Comment: You really, really need to calm down a bit. This isn't a personal attack. An answer being accepted doesn't mean that it can't or shouldn't be deleted. Users often accept very poor answers and that is why the site mechanics allow them to be removed even when the OP themselves can not delete the answer.

Comment: The age of the answer/question is also irrelevant. I feel like your other question received much useful advice for fixing it and yet you ignored it. Why? Why should we have a question with an answer that so many think does not answer the question or is poor as the top answer? Defend your answer and why you think it should remain rather than relying on MSE policy that says it doesn't have to be removed.

Comment: I don't consider it a personal attack but strongly believe the answer wouldn't have been deleted if OP had not accepted it. That makes it a retrospective and arbitrary imposition of evolved site standards. In any case I shall listen to reasons for deletion and edit the answer accordingly but leaving the answer in a deleted condition is not what I want @Catija.

Comment: But you can not accuse people of that. You need to ask why, not point fingers.

Comment: *"I am willing to improve the amswer towards getting it undeleted, but you got to tell me what's wrong with it.

Answers are especially welcome from the 3 delete-voters here because you can vote to delete again if somebody else votes to undelete."* __ I have asked why and await their response @Catija.

Comment: I don't understand why only those three people can tell you how to fix it. Tinkeringbell clearly pointed out that your answer fails to answer the **body** of the question. What other explanation do you need? We can not only address the title of the question, we must consider the full story of the body and your answer does not do that at all.

Comment: I have now substantially edited, expanded and improved my recently deleted old answer to conform to current site expectations of quality, @Catija. Users can kindly vote to undelete or explain how to further improve my answer to get it undeleted. Your constructive feedback here as well as that of Tinkeringbell on my related meta question is much appreciated.

Comment: I was wondering where that answer went...

Comment: First time I have seen an accepted answer with 5 down votes....